# Which cloud storage services support setting custom HTTP headers?

Tags: amazon-s3, http-headers, google-cloud-storage, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

For example setting a `Link` header (i.e. `Link: <https://api.github.com/search/code?q=addClass+user%3Amozilla&page=15>; rel="next"`)

AWS S3 & Google Cloud Storage don't seem to support custom headers.

Any others that do support it?

Comment: Both Amazon S3 and Google Cloud Storage support custom headers, but `Link:` is not one of them, or at least not documented (by contrast, S3 has undocumented support on the REST API for setting the `X-Robots-Tag` header).  Unless things have changed, though, browser support for the `Link` header is sketchy.

Comment: In [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33109592/1695906), I used HAProxy in EC2 in front of S3 to modify the responses from S3 to inject `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/error.xsl"?>` into the error response XML so that the browser could style those error responses.  My original attempt was to inject a `Link:` header for the same purpose, using HAProxy in front it S3, to inject it.  The injection works fine of course, and FF handled it correctly, Chrome didn't, so I had to modify the body. But this is a potentially viable alternative. Store `x-amz-meta-link:`, rewrite as `Link:`.