# How to customise UI for expired object in S3?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working in AWS S3 upload and download from bucket.  After generated URL link, it is working fine.  But after expired the URL, the below XML file displayed.

```
 <Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Request has expired</Message>
    <Expires>2017-03-31T14:49:56Z</Expires>
    <ServerTime>2017-05-04T11:32:40Z</ServerTime>
    <RequestId>...</RequestId>
     <HostId>...</HostId>
 </Error>
```

How to customise the above output or any other way to display as table or simply display "Expired"?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of [AWS S3 gracefully handle 403 after getSignedUrl expired](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33109592/1695906); however, I'm inclined at the moment not to drop my golden dupe hammer on it until others weigh in, as I don't want to appear self-serving -- I wrote the only answer at the other question.  I'm quite pleased with the solution, there, and it is not a native solution -- there is none.  My workaround requires placing a proxy in front of S3 to modify the XML to add a link to a stylesheet, and browser XSLT to style the result.  It does work nicely, however.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean to customize the above output for your application. You're not going to be able to update the error message returned back from AWS itself.

There are a few ways to go about this, but essentially, you'll need to determine if you received an error response back. From there, you can just parse it seeing as it is an XML response.

You'll of course want to catch any exceptions from parsing the XML response.

```
string data = @"<Error>
                    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
                    <Message>Request has expired</Message>
                    <Expires>2017-03-31T14:49:56Z</Expires>
                    <ServerTime>2017-05-04T11:32:40Z</ServerTime>
                    <RequestId>...</RequestId>
                     <HostId>...</HostId>
                </Error>";

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(data);
if(xdoc.Descendants("Error").Any())
{
    var errorMessage = from lv1 in xdoc.Descendants("Error")
                select lv1.Element("Message").Value;

    Console.WriteLine(errorMessage.FirstOrDefault());
}
```